# Issue regarding printing of column wise data in ejs

Tags: node.js, ejs

I am trying to print my images along with recipe names in row of 2 columns.I have written this code for that.But I am getting an error like "invalid string length".Here is my nodejs code:

```
else{
        var len = result.length;
        len = (len/2).toFixed(0);
        let recipes = result.map(row => { return { rname: row.rname, image: row.image.toString('base64')}});
        res.render("recipes_response", { recipes,len } );
    }
```

and this is my ejs code:

```
<div class="container">
            <% var k = j = 0 %>
            <% for(var i=0;i<len;i++){ %> %>
                <div class="row">
                    <% while(j<2){ %> %>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <h4>Recipe name: <%= recipes[k].rname %></h4>
                            <img src="data:image/png;base64, <%= recipes[k].image %>" alt="Recipe image" />
                        </div>
                        <% j = j++ %>
                        <% k = k++ %>
                    <% } %>
                    <% j = 0 %>
                </div>  
            <% } %>
</div>
```

and my css is:

```
.container{
                columns: 2 auto;
                margin-top: 30px;
            }
```

But I want my images to be printed in rows with two columns in each row.For example If I have two recipe_names(rname) along with their images with the ingredients I entered,then they must print in a single row in two columns.If I have 5 recipe_names along with their images,Then I need first two recipe_names and images in one row in two columns and the other two in second row in each column and the remaining one in third row in single column.How can I do this?
Can anyone help me?

Comment: This doesn't address your node / javascript question directly, but flex css is made for your row / column requirement.

Comment: Will you suggest me how to work with it?